# ImageIcon with JOptionPane not appearing in executable JAR

Tags: java, swing, embedded-resource, imageicon, getresource

As the title says,  I've been trying to get images into my JOption Message dialogs. I've gotten them to show when running it in eclipse, but when I export the file into an executable jar, the images don't load.

[image: In Eclipse]

[image: In jar executable]

```
    ImageIcon normal = new ImageIcon("src/project/normal.png");
    ImageIcon happy = new ImageIcon("src/project/happy.png");
    ImageIcon jackpot = new ImageIcon("src/project/jackpot.png");
    ImageIcon fail = new ImageIcon("src/project/fail.png");
    ImageIcon error = new ImageIcon("src/project/error.png");
```

I'm just calling the name of the ImageIcon into the JOptionPane.showMessageDialogue

Comment: Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You are currently reading the image from a file and when exporting it into an executable jar, this file is no longer available. Instead, try getting the image as an resource:

`ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/image.png"));`